# Is getExternalFilesDir(null).absolutePath fixed?

Tags: android, kotlin, file-storage

So I'm working on two apps, one writes files, the other uploads the files and delete them.
 I save the files using

```
    val file = File(content.getExternalFilesDir(null), "$fileName.csv")
```

And tested it on two different phones, both shows that file is saved to the path 
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app1/files/

My question is will the path be the same on any other phones? or will it vary from different os version and phones?

Should i hardcore the path in the upload app? or should i use Intent to send the path to the upload app?

Answer (score 0):

It's always safer to assume that the path might change - even if at this very moment it won't, future system updates might break your apps. I'd say - go for sending the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
getExternalFilesDir
```

This API will always get the same directory on same phone , so if you save file at this path , you will also can upload & delete it .

But if you hardcore a path , such as /sdcard/ you should ask for the rw_sdcard permission to do this .

But **getExternalFilesDir** doesn't need ask for permission , I'd rather suggest you keep this code .